# How to obtain a subtree of a tree using python igraph?

Tags: python, tree, igraph

I hoped there is a simple function for this purpose (e.g. `tree.subtree(vertex)`) but I was not able to find one even after browsing the documentation quite a long time.

In any case, I found this workaround:

```py
subtree = tree.induced_subgraph(tree.subcomponent(vertex, mode='out'))
```

But this seems inefficient to me as `subcomponent()` returns a list of vertices reachable from `vertex` then `induced_subgraph()` (re)creates the subtree from this vertex-list.

Any other idea? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for breadth first search, starting at your root:

```
[vertices, layers, parents] = g.bfs(root)
```

You can combine vertices and parents to get the edges of your new graph.

However, I don't think that will actually be a lot more efficient:
`subcomponent` will be based on BFS, so there will be no difference in running time there (O(|V| + |E|). `induced_subgraph` will have a running time O(|E|), so that is also the same as the running time for combining vertices and parents. The constant factors omitted by the big-O notation will be different, sure, but how big is your graph that you think those differences might matter?